# .htaccess redirect leads to all browsers saying "privacy error, connection not private"

Tags: .htaccess, privacy

So I want to redirect one of my websites including every single page to the root of another one. I did so by doing this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Now when I go to any link of my old website, I get this security warning in the  browser:

> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>   Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.olddomain.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).

The old website was `http` and the new one is `https` if that might help?

Comment: Weird that the error message would mention `www.olddomain.com` then, if that never was HTTPS. Can you reach your new domain correctly via HTTPS to begin with, when you try to access it directly?

Comment: Yes, `https` works fine on the new site.

Comment: Then what URL are you actually on, when this error is shown?

Comment: Still the old one.

Comment: HTTP or HTTPS? What do you see happening in the network panel? Redirects? From where to where exactly?

Comment: ah, interesting. So it's the old domain but with `https` which is not setup. Network panel says it's trying to get the old domain with https and fails to do so.

Comment: You are presumably requesting `http://www.olddomain.com/` (HTTP)? Yet, you are seeing `https://www.olddomain.com/` (HTTPS) in the network traffic? In which case, there must be something in the network traffic showing you how it got from `http://olddomain` to `https://olddomain/` - what does it show? Is there a redirect? And to confirm, the olddomain has _never_ had an SSL cert installed?

Comment: I suggest testing this with [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh). It might be something like the wrong virtual host is responding to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I was hosting the .htaccess accidentally on the same virtual host in Plesk as the new website. So the .htaccess was already responding with the `https` protocol. I created a new virtual host to accept connections from the domain via `http` now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. However, I would have expected that to have resulted in a redirect-loop (using the directives from your question) - a different "error" to what you reported?! A separate vHost and performing a simple `Redirect` in the vHost is preferable (no `.htaccess` required for the olddomain).

Comment: @MrWhite the options that Plesk provides me with do not work for me. Because I want every page of the old domain to point to the root of the new one. Thats why I have to use .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you directly access newdomain with the same browser? If you do not see the same error (meaning the certificate is valid), it means that the host header still contains the olddomain hostname.
You need to rewrite the host header as well, this might help:
https://serverfault.com/questions/336796/can-apache-rewrite-a-requests-host-header-based-on-the-url

Comment: I can access the new site just fine.

Comment: OK, it means that the HOST HTTP header is still set to the old site.
RewriteRule alone is not enough

Comment: "the host header still contains the olddomain" - that can't be the case here? This is a "simple" redirect, not a reverse proxy server (which is what the linked question is about). (?)

Comment: Apparently you're supposed to be right, but if you see the OLD domain in the warning message, it means that this is the case and the old domain is still set in the host header. Perhaps because it is the same host? You can verify it by using Fiddler web debugger and check the actual request that is transmitted to the new server.
Anyway, in the link I pasted above, you can see what else is needed in order to set the host header file if needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index</span>.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```